# Cauchy's Estimate for $|z|=R$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be entire and let $|f(z)|\leq M$ for $|z|=R$ and R is fixed. I want to prove that $$|f^{(k)}(re^{i\theta})|\leq \frac{k!M}{(R-r)^k}$$

I don't understand how you get R-r in the denominator. I know the Cauchy's estimate formula.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What is Cauchy's estimate formula? Do you know Cauchy's formula (not estimate …) for $f^({k})(z)$?

Comment: yes its $f^{(k)}(a)= \frac{k!}{2\pi{i}}\int_C\frac {f(z)dz}{(z-a)^k}$ am i right?

Comment: @d13 It is actually $(z-a)^{k+1}$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy's Integral Formula:

$$f^{(k)}(t)=\frac{k!}{2\pi i}\int\limits_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-t)^{k+1}}dz$$

so putting $\,z=re^{i\theta}\,$ , we get by Cauchy's Estimates

$$|f^{(k)}(re^{i\theta})|\le \frac{k!}{|2\pi i|}\max_{|z|=R}\left(\frac{|f(z)|}{|z-re^{i\theta}|^{k+1}}\right)2\pi R\le \frac{k!MR}{(R-r)^{k+1}}$$

since $\,z\in\{ z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|=R\}\;,\;\;t=re^{i\theta}\implies\,$

$$\frac1{|z-t|}\le\frac1{|z|-|re^{i\theta}|}=\frac1{R-r}$$

Comment: What happened to the R in the numerator? How does that cancel with the extra $R-r$ in the denominator?

Comment: It is there, I just forgot to write down 6 years ago...And you don't get what the OP asked.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, there shouldn't be an $R$ in the numerator at the end... according to the OP's question.

Comment: @Esmath Perhaps he forgot it (his formula is also missing one exponent more in the denominator), perhaps I just didn't reach what he wanted and he's right , though I doubt it...I just can't remember what was this, sorry.

Comment: This answer unfortunately is not what @d13 asked. If anyone is interested in how to come up with the formula they wanted to prove, have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653458/upper-bound-of-a-function-in-hoffman-and-mardstens-complex-analysis-2-8/4653563#4653563

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray This answer is almost 10 years old (!)...and of course it answers the OP's question: how to reach the denominator in Cauchy's Estimate Formula. The power is unimportant in most cases and can easily be fixed this or that way.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah more or less, but I wanted to still write it just for completeness sake so if someone else needs a proof of the formula they can just click the link.